# Is there a way to add a background to Word page but not saved in .docx file?

Tags: microsoft-word

Users can add background pictures to the Word pages, of course. But the image file will be compiled into the .docx file (thus changed the file). Now I want to find a way to add background to the Word pages opened without adding true background to the file.

That is, it should be a visual effect in Word editor and not interfere with word file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking to add a "theme" to Microsoft Word in the way that you can with a modern web browser.

The simple answer is no.  Microsoft Word does not support this.

Themes (and backgrounds) in Microsoft Word refer to elements within files.  You can place background images in files (In Word version 1910:
Design > Page Color > Fill Effects > Pictures).  By default, these are not included when printing the file.  Still, they are part of the file and will not be present when editing another file in Word.

The reason for this is simply that Word (mostly) attempts to follow a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) style, meaning that additional theming potentially conflicts with the objective of the software.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you can't set document background independently from document.

Word is a document editor with primary goal of showing results as they'll appear on print too.

What you're looking for is a different type of tool.